# Correct doctype, attributes, encoding for Chinese language

Tags: html, character-encoding

How should I modify this in order to display Chinese characters?

Those question marks are actually Chinese writings.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head> 

<body> 

?????????????????????????????

????????????????

?????????????????????,?????????????,???!

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would making sure that your editor's character encoding settings match. (i.e. change the setting to UTF-8 and try retyping/repasting). For example, in Eclipse, IIRC, the default encoding for most files is dependent on your regional settings (it will usually pick a non-UTF variant such as ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) - on my machine). Which editor are you using?